# Access a file with su

Tags: linux, shell-script

How to access a file with su and search a pattern

```
su - root exec cat /home/root/file1.txt | grep pattern search
```

Getting the below error when try to find patterns

```
**script: write :no space left on device **
```

Comment: It looks like you are out of space, try `df -h .` in the directory where you tried the above and look at Use% if it's at 100 you probably need to free some space.

Comment: Btw, what is the idea behind `cat file | grep pattern` instead of `grep pattern file`?

Comment: @BethMckey What Philippos is asking is why don't you skip the `cat` which is useless and just complicates the command? They are well aware of the difference.

Comment: Im Sorry ! The only req is file1 has 100 lines &  i need the line that matches the pattern. Even if i use grep pattern file ,the result appended t o another file has entire 100 lines.

Answer (score 1):

`su - root grep pattern /home/root/file1.txt` will do it. "no space left on device" is related to some other part of your script which tries to write data to an already full storage device.